# How to post a text on a label in another form when we are click a button on other form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I have a program in C# which does have a button. So when we click the button it's going to calculate some values in the form containing that button (`form1`) and the result is going to be displayed as a text in a label in another form (`form2`).

How am I going to do that? Anyone can explain me about the code?

Comment: it would be nice, if you add some code snippet

Comment: You need to have a reference in `Form1` to `Form2`. I assume you create the second form from the first.You then have a reference that you can use. Save it in a global variable so that you can access it from multiple methods.

Comment: Can you pleaase give me a syntax of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `Form2` variable in your `Form1`:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2;
```

Inside `Form2` create a `SetLabelText` method:

```
public void SetLabelText(string text)
{
    this.label1.Text = text;
}
```

Whenever you need to update the label on the second form:

```
f2.SetLabelText("Message generated by Form1");
```

EDIT: complete example

The first form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form2 f2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.SetLabelText("testing");
    }
}
```

The second form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetLabelText(string text)
    {
        this.label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: which i do first but i get this error "is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: @Optimuskck, what do you mean? You first create `Form1` and then `Form2`. Maybe the (edited) complete example will help you more.

Comment: form 1 -  there is some text boxes and a command button . so when i click command button the value in the text boxes will add up and post  in another label on a form 2

Comment: When you click you button on `Form1` you generate the result (add the values). Afterwards you call the `SetLabelText` method: `f2.SetLabelText(result)`.

Comment: @Optimuskck, of course it is :P. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with event. Let your form notify second form that number was calculated:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<NumberCalculatedEventArgts> NumberCalculated;

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int value = 42; // calculate value
        OnNumberCalculated(value); // Notify subscribers
    }

    protected void OnNumerCalculated(int value)
    {
        if (NumberCalculated != null) // Check if somebody needs notification
           NumberCalculated(this, new NumberCalculatedEventArgs(value));
    }
}
```

Second form should subscribe to event of this form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void ShowCalclulatorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.NumberCalculated += Form1_NumerCalculated; // Subscribe
        form1.Show();
    }

    void Form1_NumerCalculated(object sender, NumberCalculatedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.Value.ToString(); // Handle notification
    }
}
```

And last thing you need is custom event args to provide calculated value:

```
public class NumberCalculatedEventArgts : EventArgs
{
    public NumberCalculatedEventArgts(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
}
```

---

You also can use `Action` instead of custom event handler to make solution more compact:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event Action<int> NumberCalculated;

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int value = 42; // calculate value
        if (NumberCalculated != null)
            NumberCalculaed(value);
    }
}
```